# Automatic Code formatting conflicts with Javascript Lint in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, formatting, jslint

To enable effective code formatting, I need to set the following in my `.vimrc` file

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

If I do that, code formatting (`gg=G`) works perfectly. However, I get the following error when I load up javascript files:

```
Error detected while parsing function <SNR>78_JSLint:
line 25
could not invoke JSLint
```

and I have to set it back to

```
filetype on
```

Now Javascript Lint works (I don't know why it says 'JSLint', I have Syntastic set up to work with Javascript Lint), but code formatting is now less reliable. How do I make it so I can run Javascript Lint (via Syntastic) and proper code formatting, without one interfering with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have another JS linting plugin somewhere (maybe jslint.vim?) that conflicts with syntastic or you don't have said plugin anymore but there's stil an `autocmd` in your .vimrc.

Search your `~/.vim` folder for "JSLint" with

```
$ grep JSLint ~/.vim
```

to see where it's invoked.

Either way, your problem has nothing to do with indenting.

Comment: would this conflict only arise when I set `filetype plugin indent on`? Could you please elaborate as to why this plugin would only be used when I add the `plugin indent` to `filetype on`

Comment: you were right. I had a plugin file in ~.vim/ftplugins/javascript`. Thanks